# Trying to link pages using reactRouter created a button link, when i press btn the current page remains and requested page appears parallel to it

Tags: reactjs

[Parallele pages side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPbt7.png)

Tried the switch option of react router, im using version 6 so it gives an error.

Tried an html anchor tag the URL changes but content does not change.

[App.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYlsa.png)
[Signup with google component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWGpg.png)